# In rgl, is it possible to change the color of vertices without passing the coordinates again?

Tags: r, rgl

For example, let's say I am trying to draw a quadrilateral with `quads3d`, and I've made a call with this function once and I've got a nice colored quadrilateral.

If I want to draw the same quadrilateral, i.e. same position, but with different color what I currently do is to remove the old quadrilateral and draw new one with new colors. I have a use case where the quadrilateral (actually a bunch of them) is always the same, only the color changes. Can I save memory/processing and somehow instruct rgl to just change the color of the already drawn quadrilateral?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really do that.  There are ways that hide the delete/redraw cycle, but none actually save memory or time.

So your general approach should be something like this:

```
library(rgl)

open3d()
xyz <- cbind(x = c(0,1,1,0,2,3,3,2), y = 0, z = c(0,0,1,1))
quads <- quads3d(xyz, col = rainbow(8))
saveSkip <- par3d(skipRedraw = TRUE)
pop3d(id = quads)
quads <- quads3d(xyz, col = terrain.colors(8))
par3d(saveSkip)
```

This will be close to as fast as you could get it without going into the C++ and modifying the source.